# Is there a silent fail for Selenium driver driver.Navigate().GoToUrl();

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

Hi I am using PhantomJS with Selenium to query some web pages.

Throughout I have used the following code to go from the main product page to a minisite

```
var miniSiteSrc1 = miniSite1.GetAttribute("href");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(miniSiteSrc1);
```

With a particular URl it doesn't seem to work:

http://media.flixcar.com/delivery/minisite/show/2348/en/823885

When using the exact same code with the following url it seems to work fine:

http://www.isitetv.com/en062124184249062123148173198223-p10.htm

Any ideas why this might be happening and if there's anything I can do about it?

Many thanks

Comment: Do you get the same result if you use `driver.get(miniSiteSrc1)`?

Comment: Hi @MarkRowlands its doesn't seem to like driver.get (I get cannot resolve symbol)  I also tried driver.Url = miniSiteSrc1; but it didn t like that either.

Comment: Can't resolve `driver.get()` that's very odd - that's one of the key methods to the class. Which version of Webdriver are you running?

Comment: its web driver v 4.0.30319 I ve actually found the solution and it was something really silly that I added earlier - I had some code to ignore certain urls so the page wouldn t take a long time to load and flix was one of them!  thanks for your time!